# What is the purpose of the controller in the MVC pattern using PHP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am just heading into MVC design pattern. A simple example here does not clear my concept about the use of controller. Could you please explain real use of controller while keeping it simple.

Model:

```
    class Model {
       public $text;

       public function __construct() {
           $this->text = 'Hello world!';
       }        
    }
```

Controller:

```
      class Controller {
          private $model;

          public function __construct(Model $model) {
              $this->model = $model;
          }
      }
```

View:

```
      class View {
         private $model;
         //private $controller;

         public function __construct(/*Controller $controller,*/ Model $model) {
             //$this->controller = $controller;
             $this->model = $model;
         }

          public function output() {
               return '<h1>' . $this->model->text .'</h1>';
         }

      }
```

index:

```
      require_once('Model.php'); 
      require_once('Controller.php');
      require_once('View.php');

      //initiate the triad
      $model = new Model();
      //It is important that the controller and the view share the model
      //$controller = new Controller($model);
      $view = new View(/*$controller,*/ $model);
      echo $view->output();
```

Comment: Controller passes data between view and model

Comment: Controller takes user input and processes it and decides which view to show in response

Comment: If you check my code, there is no need to use controller, view can take data directly from model. Why use controller?

Comment: Your last file is sometimes known as a "front controller", which is the file called by the web server. It should be calling the actual controller, but that seems to be commented out. I'd move the model and view instantiation to the actual controller too. In your design, the front controller could take care of _routing_ and instantiate the correct controller based on that.

Comment: If you don't use controller how you will pass model to view?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad please run my code to understand how view can take data directly from model

Comment: but it is not the convention of mvc pattern

Comment: View is only responsible for displaying, you should not create model objects in there

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Comment: Well, no model object is created inside view, instead the model object is received there that contains data and the output function is responsible to display that data. I think this is what view is for. I don't understand why view needs controller while it needs model (having the data)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski could you please explain controller's need through an example?

Comment: No, because you will find countless tutorials discussing MVC in details all over the net.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski those tutorials also just happen to have nothing to do with MVC and instead describe how to re-implement Rails-like architecture in PHP.

Answer (score 8):

Controllers purpose in MVC pattern is to alter the state of model layer.

It's done by controller receiving user input *(preferable - abstracted as some thing like `Request` instance)* and then, based on parameters that are extracted from the user input, passes the values to appropriate parts of model layer.

The communication with model layer usually happens via various [services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_%28systems_architecture%29). These services in turn are responsible for governing the interaction between persistence abstraction and domain/business objects, or also called "application logic".

#### Example:

```
class Account extends \Components\Controller
{

    private $recognition;

    public function __construct(\Model\Services\Recognition $recognition)
    {
        $this->recognition = $recognition;
    }

    public function postLogin($request)
    {    
        $this->recognition->authenticate(
            $request->getParameter('credentials'),
            $request->getParameter('method')
        );
    }

    // other methods
    
}
```

#### What is controller **NOT** responsible for?

Controllers in MVC architectural pattern are **NOT** responsible for:

- initializing parts of model layer
- retrieving data from model layer
- validation of input
- initializing views
- selecting templates
- creating response
- access control
- .. etc.

Answer (score -3):

The controller in PHP ( or in fact in any server language, would be the one that handles the url that is called) So i will have to rewrite your above code it would be

Main file; this in fact will be your main controller or router, this is the first file that is called and usually would be called index.php ( in this file just create an instance of controller, no need to create model and view since they will be in purview of controller as to which model and view to use)

```
require_once('Controller.php');

//check the user url and decide which controller to instantiate. This is usually done by a separate file called controller factory. But for simplicity we use take this decision here itself.
$controller = new Controller()
//call controllers default method and let it decide which internal function to call
$controller->index()
```

Controller file => Here instantiate the model and view. The advantage is the model and view can be changed if required in the controller itself

```
require_once "Model.php"
require_once "View.php"
class Controller {
private $model;
private $view;

public function _contruct() {
// i may and may not initialize my mocel or view here, better initialize it in the function where you are going to use them.
}

public function index() {
// for now assume this controller just does one function that is to display the hello world. Otherwise we will read the called url and decide which further function to call
$model = new Model();
$view = new View($model); // pass the model to view
$view->output()  // don't ideally echo here, let view itself echo the content. This is helpfull  cases where you may have a view which echos the content or may want to format it in certain way (e.g JSON and return it to the caller
}
```

That's pretty much it . I dont see any code changes in your model or view files. Theu shoudl work as is except you will echo the content in view instead of returning it.

Comment: There are many errors in your code. By the way, I fixed them all in my copy