# Where to validate users input?

Tags: php, validation, oop

I am developing a new application using object oriented approach with some REST involved, I am not using any frameworks.

The question I have is where is the best place to validate a user’s input in a setter like below:

```
public function setSalary($salary)
{
    if (Validator::money($salary))
        $this->salary = $salary;
    else
        return 'Error that is an invalid number';
}
```

Or in the controller?

```
public function updateSalary()
{
    $errors = array();

    if (Validator::money($_POST['salary']))
        $salary = $_POST['salary'];
        else
            $errors ['salary']  = 'Error that is an invalid number';

    if(count($errors))
        return $errors;

    $employee = new Employee($_POST['e_Id']);
    $employee->setSalary($salary);

    $employee->save();
}
```

If I was to put in the setter how should my controller look, and return validation errors?

I have seen most people do validation in the controller, however I think should be the models responsibility for validation as it going to be using the data, and we can reuse that model without repeating ourselves. 
However there can be times when validation rules may need to be different in some special cases like different validation for a different view or different validation for a supper admin.

Which one would you say is in accordance with best practices?

Comment: Fact, that data comes from user input, is just a "detail". What you should validate is that the `Employee` instance is in a valid state. And you probably should also attempt to catch any exceptions, that might be thrown from the persistence layer.

Comment: User's inputs must be validated in controller (ex: invalid id - integer expected). Business logic validations should be done in services/models (ex: no such user id)

Comment: @MateiMihai that's completely wrong. Controllers are not responsible for data validation. And how would the business rules, that you validate against, end up in that "controller"?

Comment: @Mjh who is the "he" that you are referring to? Invalidity of and ID depends on how it is used. It's the `Employee`  instance, that know, that the ID must be a number, and not "115-124-1555".

Answer (score 8):

First of all, since you seem to aspire to implement MVC-like structure, lets start by some general mistakes, that are not related to validation directly.

- Only part of your code, containing PHP superglobals, should be the bootstrap stage. Having superglobals sprinkled all over your code makes it really hard to test. And your code also becomes tightly couple to your HTML, via the `<input>` names.
- Even if your `for` or `if` statement contains a single line, you should always use curly brackets. Well, in general your code should follow the [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) guidelines.
- Controllers should not have any logic, or be dealing with saving of data. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25709651/727208), maybe it clears some things up.

Ok .. now back to the original subject.

In general there are two schools of thought:

1. **You do the validation in the domain entity**

   Your domain entity (in your case `Employee`) contains all the business roles, that pertain to it. And it can use those rules to assess, if it is in a valid state.

   The code would go something like this:

   ```
   $employee = new Entity\Employee;
   $employee->setID($id);
   $employee->setSalary($money);    
   if ($employee->isValid()) {
       $mapper = new Mapper\Employee($dbConn);
       $mapper->store($emplyee);
   }
   ```
2. **You never create invalid domain entity**

   This approach comes from [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design), where you domain entity is created by some other class and it can only be changes from one valid state to another valid state. Essentially, if you want to explore this approach, you will have to read [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) (probably several times).

Also, there is one other validation form, which is note covered by the previous two: data integrity checks. This is type of validation, that is actually done my RDBMS. For example, the `UNIQUE` constraints.

When you encounter ans integrity violation, it usually would throw an exception, that you handle in service layer.

Comment: Always helpful and to point explanations :),but what global in bootstrap stage contains??

Comment: It is recommended  to check the uniqueness and data types before sending any data to rdbms. Even if the rdbms has its own constrains the app is the one which should handle them. Think about different storage systems like mysql, mongodb, redis, memcache which have different approaches in storing data..

Comment: @MateiMihai I really don't see how this would change anything. The data mapper would still throw an exceptions. It doesn't really matter if it was triggered by a manual check or by something emanating from the storage abstraction (be it postrgres or coutchdb).

Answer (score 2):

Validation must be called every time you write data to the database. So in this case from the controller. The actual validation happens in the model. The model is the object, that knows which rules it's fields obey and it can check whether the data is valid or not. Also, the model is the border between the rest of the world and the database. So, I would do something like this:

```
public function updateSalary()
{
    $employee = new Employee($_POST['e_Id']);
    $employee->setSalary($_POST['salary']));
    if ($employee->validate()) {
        $employee->save();             
    } else {
        return $employee->getErrors();
    }
}
```

Why I offer you this way:

- because you keep the validation at one place. Later, if you want to validate another field, you will call the validate() method again. You won't write another validation for each field or class;
- You can create a base class and put the validate() method there - all clients will call the validate() method, and wouldn't care about the specifics of the fields. The validate method will care only of what to validate - which fields and what the rules are. This information will be set in the specific (child) classes, like the Employee class.
- If you want to validate only one field (like in your case), in the validate() method you can make a simple check of which fields are changed and do validation only of these fields.

Comment: imo, I would never allow the `model` to see the 'raw input' ($_POST etc.). It will see a 'formalized object' i.e. a 'Data Transfer Object' (DTO) that was created 'upstream' by a 'controller' etc. It may be a copy of $_POST but it doesn't know that. It will also return a 'DTO' that can be passed around. It will contain error messages etc.

Comment: Ok, I agree with that. I just created a simplified version in order to give the idea. I had to mention that. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

Depends of you, if the validation rules are "global", in other words if they are the same every time you update that DB table/Object propriety, place them in the Model, otherwise validate user input in the Controller if in different situations you need different validation rules for the same Entity.

Comment: What about if you have 3 interfaces which uses the same models? ex: soap request, rest request and xmlrpc request.. user's input validation means that first you must validate the soap, rest or xmlrpc request parameters before send any information to the models. The model must use the same data type and must do business logic validations

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I am not a geek below is just what I think.

It should be done in controller, just because right now you are only validating number, which just simple check and I think you just have to apply regex for this.

What actually I understand is that, model is where you keep your business logic, but if your field value is all together wrong than you will never process business logic and you don't want your model to come in play.

Comment: Same validation in two different places? Someone changes one but not the other? Why? The `model` (not database model) has to do all the validations and record state. Controller not updated - doesn't pass valid data? The model is always updated with the latest rules. Anything else leads to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to apply validation in the Model where possible. It has the advantage that the Model can be tested directly in a more complete way, and that the Model is guaranteed to only persist valid data.

Of course, the Controller needs to *handle* validation, and might be the first layer that calls on validation when it concerns complex validation on distributed items. But in the example you give there is no such complexity.

Note that anyway some validation will even be performed by the database engine (such as `NOT NULL` and primary key requirements).

I would also suggest to use exceptions in the Model, as this guarantees the interruption of the running function, and lets you process all (validation) errors in a similar way within the Controller. I would advise to configure your database access layer to also trigger exceptions. In case of PDO you would do that as follows:

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

In the Model you would throw an exception when validation fails:

```
public function setSalary($salary) {
    if (!Validator::money($salary)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid value provided as salary.');
    }
    $this->salary = $salary;
}
```

In the Controller you would catch errors and log them: as you did in *$errors*, but I would keep them in the Model as well for later access by the View. This illustrates how the Model detects the validation error, but the Controller deals with it.

I would also suggest to not create an Employee instance directly, but to let the Model do that for you:

```
public function updateSalary($emp_id, $salary) {
    try {    
        // Note that any of the following statements could trigger exceptions:
        $employee = $this->$model->getEmployee($emp_id);
        $employee->setSalary($salary);
        $employee->save();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->$model->logError('salary', $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Call the latter function with the posted arguments, as this gives a better indication what the method is using as input. The top-level PHP code would look like this:

```
$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($controller, $model);

$controller->updateSalary($_POST['e_Id'], $_POST['salary']);

echo $view->output();
```

The View would access to the logged errors to report them to the client.

I realise that the debate as to where to detect validation errors, where handle them, when to trigger exceptions (and when not), ... etc, will never end. But this works for me.

Comment: imo, any exception is a failure unless it is a 'valid exception' that can be processed. These are rare.  Normally, The only thing to be done is report them. And, sadly, imo,  the kindest action to take, in development and testing, it to kill the process ;-/ At least someone will look at it? In production then they get escalated. So, imo,  don't catch exceptions. In production, have an `error handler` that reports them - always.

Comment: I agree. The place to implement the (production) error handler is in the Controller, which is what I suggest. The place where to report them to can be: to the user (View) in a way that does not reveal sensitive information, and in logs, which would be done in the `logError` method I proposed. That could even trigger an email to an admin, etc. In most cases the Controller is the one who "decides" on the severity of an exception and what to do with it.

Comment: Maybe the downvoter could explain what the issue is?

Comment: Like yourself - I don't understand the 'downvote'. Also like yourself, I so wish they would explain _why_ they didn't agree so strongly ;-/ At least we could then learn about the viewpoint they have.

Comment: Reason for -1: potentially harmful PDO initialization, what the hell `$this->model->getEmployee()` does (is it a service locator?), using active-record pattern, saying that controllers handle logging .. oh, and "model" is not a class (especially not a generic class at that).

Comment: I take your points, @tereško, thank you for raising them. I certainly don't claim the model is a class, it is a matter of organisation, which can be equally (better?) done with separation into files, folder structures, name spaces, etc. All very interesting to change thoughts and experiences about. It is indeed debatable what the role is of the controller (if any) in error handling. Talk with 10 people and you get 10 different opinions depending on which books they have read.

Comment: The main point about controllers is that there shouldn't be information being passed back from model to it. The reason,  why you ended up doing this, is because you are fiddling directly with the `Employee` in a controller (both persisting and altering it). You have code yourself in a proverbial corner. You end up bringing more and more business logic in the controller and to grows fatter and fatter.

Comment: I see your point, but the opinions on that differ. See for instance [Wikipedia 's example for Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Controller_Class) and the flows depicted in the image that goes with it. Wikipedia is of course no infallible reference (its even flagged as "unbalanced view"), but it's not the only one saying that the communication between controller and model is bi-directional. I really don't want to be polemic about that, it's just clear that MVC means different things to different people. I appreciate your feed-back.

Comment: @trincot you have misunderstood a bit. What wikipedia article talks about are applications, that have .. emm .. long living objects (think - desktop apps). The reason for any information coming back from M to C is, when a change in Model's state has to change Controller's available actions (like, when user gains authorization to perform some secured activity). And even those rare cases are implemented using observer pattern (M pushing, instead of C pulling).

Comment: You removed the section I referred to on Wikipedia. To not make my previous comment look ridiculous I provide the [link to the version](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller&oldid=710447780#Controller_Class) I was then looking at. The example code there is clearly not about desktop applications, and performs bi-directional communication on an object that is created on the spot. I will not continue this discussion for obvious reasons.