# PHP/MVC/PDO - beginTransaction outside of Database class

Tags: php, class, model-view-controller, methods, pdo

could someone help me on this? I have following classes (all functional, abbreviated here for sake of legibility):

```
  class Database {
    private $host = DB_HOST;
    // etc...

    public function __construct() {
     $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
     $options = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

     try {
       $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);

     } catch (PDOException $e) {
       $this->error = $e->getMessage();
       echo $this->error;
     }
   }

   public function beginTransaction() {
     $this->stmt = $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
   }
```

and a class for let’s say books;

```
  class Books extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
      $this->model = $this->loadModel('BookModel');
    }

    // etc.
    $this->model->beginTransaction();
```

and the BookModel looks like:

```
class BookModel {
  protected $db;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new Database;
  }

  public function beginTransaction() {
    $this->db->beginTransaction();
  }
```

I know I can only access the PDO beginTransaction inside of the Database class, but is there another way, or I have to use this complicated path, call the method that calls the method that calls the PDO method?

I have a feeling I’m doing something very stupid here. Maybe extending the BookModel to the Database class, but that doesn’t feel right either.

Thanks!

Comment: What about having a single database connection instead of killing your database server with dozens connections made from the same PHP script instance?

Comment: There are no dozens connections, the single time where the db connection is created is inside the Database class. The other methods calls it indirectly to assure architectural integrity.

Comment: sorry? what do you think `$this->db = new Database;` does?

Comment: Yes, but that’s called only once, or am I missing something?

Comment: That's called once in the single instance of a single model class. When you need another instance it is called again. When you need another model, it is called again. And again. And - closer to your problem at hand - you cannot use a transaction involving different models, because each model is using its own connection

Comment: If you want to seperate your code properly, you should not instantiate a new database class within your models

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean with dozens of connections, I apologize. Okay, I’ll take a look at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some suggestions:**

**[a]** You shouldn't create objects (with *"new"*) inside class methods. Instead you should inject existent instances into constructors/setters. This is named **dependency injection** and can be applied with a **dependency injection container**.

- [Dependency Injection and Dependency Inversion in PHP - James Mallison - PHPTour 2017 Nantes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIe6D81kr2g)
- [PHP-DI The dependency injection container for humans](https://php-di.org/)

**[b]** Indeed, inject a single PDO instance in the constructor. Injection is the job of the DI container. For example, in [PHP-DI](https://php-di.org/):

```
return [
    'database-connection' => function (ContainerInterface $container) {
        $parameters = $container->get('database.connection');

        $dsn = $parameters['dsn'];
        $username = $parameters['username'];
        $password = $parameters['password'];

        $connectionOptions = [
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        ];

        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $connectionOptions);

        return $connection;
    },
    Database::class => autowire()
        ->constructorParameter('connection', get('database-connection')),
];
```

The `Database` contructor:

```
public function __construct(PDO $connection) {
    $this->dbh = $connection;
}
```

**[c]** The **model** is not a class. It is a layer (**model layer**, or [**domain model**](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html)), composed of multiple components: **entities** (or **domain objects**), [**value objects**](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/valueObject.html), [**data mappers**](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), [**repositories**](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), **domain services**. Your `BookModel` is a combination btw. an entity and a data mapper. Note: inheriting it from `Database` is wrong, because a model can't be a database.

- [How should a model be structured in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/9455607)
- [The difference between domains, domain models, object models and domain objects](https://www.codewithjason.com/difference-domains-domain-models-object-models-domain-objects/)

**[d]** You shouldn't inject models into controllers. Instead, controllers should use so-called [**application services**](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html). They contain the **application logic** and are the proper way to decouple the **presentation layer** (or **delivery mechanism**) - which, among other components, includes the controllers and the views - from the domain model. The application services also assure the communication btw. the two layers. Note: there could also be **domain services**, specific to the domain and separated from the application services, which are specific to the application.

- [Sandro Mancuso : Crafted Design](https://vimeo.com/107963073)
- [Ruby Midwest 2011 - Keynote: Architecture the Lost Years by Robert Martin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpkDN78P884)
- [Robert "Uncle Bob" Martin - Architecture: The Lost Years](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhNIttd87xs)
- [How should a model be structured in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/9455607)

**[e]** `Database` class is not needed at all! You already have the very elegant & powerful PDO at disposal, to handle the database operations.

**[f]** Actually, it is not wrong to *"call the method that calls the method that calls the PDO method"*. Each method in this chain encapsulates a certain behavior, specific to the current object. Though, the functionality of each method should add some plus value. Otherwise, it wouldn't make sense to have this chain, indeed. An example: In an application service, you can directly use a **data mapper** to fetch a book by id from the database:

```
class FindBooksService {

    public function __construct(
        private BookMapper $bookMapper
    ) {

    }

    public function findBookById(?int $id = null): ?Book {
        return $this->bookMapper->fetchBookById($id);
    }

}


class BookMapper {

    public function __construct(
        private PDO $connection
    ) {
        
    }

    public function fetchBookById(?int $id): ?Book {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1';

        // Fetch book data from database; convert the record to a Book object ($book).
        //...

        return $book;
    }

}
```

Now, you could use a **repository** instead, to hide even the fact that the queried data comes from a database. This makes sense, since a repository object is seen as a collection of objects of a certain type (here `Book`) by other components. Therefore, the other components think that the repository is a collection of books, not a bunch of data in some database, and they ask the repository for them correspondingly. The repository will, in turn, interogate the data mapper to query the database. So, the previous code becomes:

```
class FindBooksService {

    /**
     * @param BookCollection $bookCollection The repository: a collection of books, e.g. of Book instances.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private BookCollection $bookCollection
    ) {

    }

    public function findBookById(?int $id = null): ?Book {
        return $this->bookCollection->findBookById($id);
    }

}

class BookCollection {

    private array $books = [];

    public function __construct(
        private BookMapper $bookMapper
    ) {
        
    }

    /**
     * This method adds a plus value to the method fetchBookById() in the data mapper:
     * - caches the Book instances in the $books list, therefore reducing the database querying operations;
     * - hides the fact, that the data comes from a database, from the external world, e.g. other components.
     * - provides an elegant collection-like interface.
     */
    public function findBookById(?int $id): ?Book {
        if (!array_key_exists($id, $this->books)) {
            $book = $this->bookMapper->fetchBookById($id);
            
            $this->books[id] = $book;
        }

        return $this->books[$id];
    }

}

class BookMapper {

    // the same...

}
```

**[g]** A "real" mistake would be to pass an object through other objects, just to be used by the last object.

**Alternative example code:**

I wrote some code as an alternative to yours. I hope it will help you better understand, how the components of an MVC-based application could work together.

**Important**: Notice the namespace `SampleMvc/Domain/Model/`: that's the **domain model**. Note that the application services, e.g. all components from `SampleMvc/App/Service/`, should communicate ONLY with the domain model components, e.g. with the components from `SampleMvc/Domain/Model/` (mostly interfaces), not from `SampleMvc/Domain/Infrastructure/`. In turn, the DI container of your choice will take care of injecting the proper class implementations from `SampleMvc/Domain/Infrastructure/` for the interfaces of `SampleMvc/Domain/Model/` used by the application services.

Notice the method `updateBook()` in `SampleMvc/Domain/Infrastructure/Book/PdoBookMapper.php`. It contains transaction code.

***Project structure:***

[image: Directory structure]

Let's assume the definition of the following routes (maybe found in a "/config/routes.php" file):

```
<?php

use SampleMvc\App\{
    Controller\Book\AddBook as AddBookController,
    View\Book\AddBook as AddBookView,
    View\Book\FindBooks as FindBooksView,
};

// Adds/updates a book record in the database.
$routeCollection->post('/books/add', [
    'controller' => AddBookController::class,
    'view' => AddBookView::class,
]);

// Finds books by author name.
$routeCollection->get('/books/find/{authorName}', [
    FindBooksView::class, 'findBooksByAuthorName',
]);
```

All objects of the application should be created by a dependency injection container.

Though, without it, the code for creating and calling the controller and/or the view could look like this:

***File "index.php" in case a "POST" request for adding a book is performed:***

```
<?php

use SampleMvc\App\{
    Controller\Book\AddBook as AddBookController,
    View\Book\AddBook as AddBookView,
};

// [...]

$addBookView = new AddBookView($addBookService, $responseFactory, $templateRenderer);
$addBookController = new AddBookController($addBookService);

// Controller updates the domain model.
$addBookController($request);

// View queries the domain model and returns the response.
$response = $addBookView($request);

// Emitter displays the response to the user.
$responseEmitter->emit($response);
```

***File "index.php" in case a "GET" request for finding a list of books is performed:***

```
<?php

use SampleMvc\App\View\Book\FindBooks as FindBooksView;

// [...]

// Note: No controller needed for just querying the domain model!

// View queries the domain model.
$findBooksView = new FindBooksView($findBooksService, $responseFactory, $templateRenderer);

// View queries the domain model and returns the response.
$response = $findBooksView->findBooksByAuthorName($authorName);

// Emitter displays the response to the user.
$responseEmitter->emit($response);
```

***SampleMvc/App/Controller/Book/AddBook.php:***

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\App\Controller\Book;

use SampleMvc\App\Service\Book\AddBook as AddBookService;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

/**
 * A controller for adding a book.
 */
class AddBook {

    /**
     * @param AddBookService $addBookService An application service.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private readonly AddBookService $addBookService
    ) {
        
    }

    /**
     * Add a book.
     * 
     * The book details (author name, book title) are 
     * submitted from a form, using the HTTP method "POST".
     * 
     * @param ServerRequestInterface $request A server request.
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request): void {
        // Get the POST values, submitted by the form.
        $authorName = $request->getParsedBody()['authorName'];
        $title = $request->getParsedBody()['title'];

        // Add the book. Expect no result from this operation!
        $this->addBookService->addBook($authorName, $title);
    }

}
```

***SampleMvc/App/View/View.php:***

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\App\View;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseFactoryInterface;
use SampleLib\Template\Renderer\TemplateRendererInterface;

/**
 * View.
 */
abstract class View {

    /**
     * A message to display to the user.
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $userMessage = '';

    /**
     * @param ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory Response factory.
     * @param TemplateRendererInterface $templateRenderer Template renderer.
     */
    public function __construct(
        protected readonly ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory,
        protected readonly TemplateRendererInterface $templateRenderer
    ) {
        
    }

    /**
     * Set the message to display to the user.
     * 
     * @param string $userMessage A message.
     * @return static
     */
    public function setUserMessage(string $userMessage): static {
        $this->userMessage = $userMessage;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

***SampleMvc/App/View/Book/AddBook.php:***

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\App\View\Book;

use SampleMvc\App\{
    View\View,
    Service\Book\AddBook as AddBookService,
};
use Psr\Http\Message\{
    ResponseInterface,
    ServerRequestInterface,
    ResponseFactoryInterface,
};
use SampleLib\Template\Renderer\TemplateRendererInterface;

/**
 * A view for adding a book.
 */
class AddBook extends View {

    /**
     * @param AddBookService $addBookService An application service.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private readonly AddBookService $addBookService,
        ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory,
        TemplateRendererInterface $templateRenderer,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($responseFactory, $templateRenderer);
    }

    /**
     * Display the result of adding a book.
     * 
     * @param ServerRequestInterface $request A server request.
     * @return ResponseInterface The response to the current request.
     */
    public function _invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface {
        /*
         * Get the POST values, submitted by the form.
         * They are only used to display a detailed message to the user.
         */
        $authorName = $request->getParsedBody()['authorName'];
        $title = $request->getParsedBody()['title'];

        // Set the user message.
        $userMessage = $this->addBookService->getBookAlreadyExists() ?
            'A book with the author name "' . $authorName() . '" '
            . 'and the title "' . $title . '" already exists' :
            'The book with the ID "' . $this->addBookService->getIdOfUpdatedBook() . '" successfully added'
        ;

        // Set the content to display to the user.
        $bodyContent = $this->templateRenderer->render('@Templates/Book/AddBook.html.twig', [
            'userMessage' => $this->setUserMessage($userMessage),
        ]);

        // Create the response to be returned to the user.
        $response = $this->responseFactory->createResponse();
        $response->getBody()->write($bodyContent);

        return $response;
    }

}
```

***SampleMvc/App/View/Book/FindBooks.php:***

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\App\View\Book;

use SampleMvc\App\{
    View\View,
    Service\Book\FindBooks as FindBooksService,
};
use Psr\Http\Message\{
    ResponseInterface,
    ResponseFactoryInterface,
};
use SampleLib\Template\Renderer\TemplateRendererInterface;

/**
 * A view for finding books.
 */
class FindBooks extends View {

    /**
     * @param FindBooksService $findBooksService An application service.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private readonly FindBooksService $findBooksService,
        ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory,
        TemplateRendererInterface $templateRenderer,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($responseFactory, $templateRenderer);
    }

    /**
     * Find books by author name.
     * 
     * The author name is provided by clicking on a link of some author name 
     * in the browser. The author name is therefore sent using the HTTP method 
     * "GET" and passed as argument to this method by a route dispatcher.
     * 
     * @param string|null $authorName (optional) An author name.
     * @return ResponseInterface The response to the current request.
     */
    public function findBooksByAuthorName(?string $authorName = null): ResponseInterface {
        // Query the domain model for a list of books by author name.
        $books = $this->findBooksService->findBooksByAuthorName($authorName);

        // Set the content to display to the user.
        $bodyContent = $this->templateRenderer->render('@Templates/Book/FindBooks.html.twig', [
            'books' => $books,
        ]);
        
        // Create the response to be returned to the user.
        $response = $this->responseFactory->createResponse();
        $response->getBody()->write($bodyContent);

        return $response;
    }

}
```

***SampleMvc/App/Service/Book/AddBook.php:***

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\App\Service\Book;

use SampleMvc\Domain\Model\Book\{
    Book,
    BookMapper,
};

/**
 * An application service for adding a book.
 */
class AddBook {

    /**
     * Determine if a book already exists on addition, or not.
     * 
     * @var bool
     */
    public bool $bookAlreadyExists = false;

    /**
     * The id under which a provided book is stored or updated.
     * 
     * @var int|null
     */
    public ?int $idOfUpdatedBook = null;

    /**
     * @param BookMapper $bookMapper A data mapper for transfering books to and from a persistence system.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private readonly BookMapper $bookMapper
    ) {
        
    }

    /**
     * Add a book.
     * 
     * @param string|null $authorName An author name.
     * @param string|null $title A title.
     * @return void
     */
    public function addBook(?string $authorName, ?string $title): void {
        $book = $this->createBook($authorName, $title);

        $this->storeBook($book);
    }

    /**
     * Create a book.
     * 
     * @param string|null $authorName An author name.
     * @param string|null $title A title.
     * @return Book The newly created book.
     */
    private function createBook(?string $authorName, ?string $title): Book {
        return new Book($authorName, $title);
    }

    /**
     * Store a book.
     * 
     * @param Book $book A book.
     * @return void
     */
    private function storeBook(Book $book): void {
        $this->bookAlreadyExists = $this->bookMapper->bookExists($book);

        if (!$this->bookAlreadyExists) {
            $this->idOfUpdatedBook = $this->bookMapper->saveBook($book);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the flag determining if a book already exists on addition, or not.
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getBookAlreadyExists(): bool {
        return $this->bookAlreadyExists;
    }

    /**
     * Get the id under which a provided book is stored or updated.
     * 
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getIdOfUpdatedBook(): ?int {
        return $this->idOfUpdatedBook;
    }

}
```

***SampleMvc/App/Service/Book/FindBooks.php:***

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\App\Service\Book;

use SampleMvc\Domain\Model\Book\{
    Book,
    BookMapper,
};

/**
 * An application service for finding books.
 */
class FindBooks {

    /**
     * @param BookMapper $bookMapper A data mapper for transfering books to and from a persistence system.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private readonly BookMapper $bookMapper
    ) {
        
    }

    /**
     * Find books by author name.
     * 
     * @param string|null $authorName (optional) An author name.
     * @return Book[] The found books list.
     */
    public function findBooksByAuthorName(?string $authorName = null): array {
        return $this->bookMapper->fetchBooksByAuthorName($authorName);
    }

    /**
     * Find a book by id.
     * 
     * @param int|null $id (optional) A book id.
     * @return Book|null The found book, or null if no book was found.
     */
    public function findBookById(?int $id = null): ?Book {
        return $this->bookMapper->fetchBookById($id);
    }

}
```

***SampleMvc/Domain/Infrastructure/Book/PdoBookMapper.php:***

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\Domain\Infrastructure\Book;

use SampleMvc\Domain\Model\Book\{
    Book,
    BookMapper,
};
use PDO;

/**
 * A data mapper for transfering Book entities to and from a database.
 * 
 * This class uses a PDO instance as database connection.
 */
class PdoBookMapper implements BookMapper {

    /**
     * @param PDO $connection Database connection.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private PDO $connection
    ) {
        
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function bookExists(Book $book): bool {
        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM books WHERE author_name = :author_name AND title = :title';

        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute([
            ':author_name' => $book->getAuthorName(),
            ':title' => $book->getTitle(),
        ]);

        $data = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return ($data['cnt'] > 0) ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function saveBook(Book $book): Book {
        if (isset($book->getId())) {
            return $this->updateBook($book);
        }
        return $this->insertBook($book);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function fetchBookById(?int $id): ?Book {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1';

        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute([
            'id' => $id,
        ]);

        $record = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return ($record === false) ?
            null :
            $this->convertRecordToBook($record)
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function fetchBooksByAuthorName(?string $authorName): array {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE author_name = :author_name';

        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute([
            'author_name' => $authorName,
        ]);

        $recordset = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $this->convertRecordsetToBooksList($recordset);
    }

    /**
     * Update a book.
     * 
     * This method uses transactions as example.
     * 
     * Note: I never worked with transactions, but I 
     * think the code in this method is not wrong.
     * 
     * @link https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#transactions (The only proper) PDO tutorial: Transactions
     * @link https://phpdelusions.net/pdo (The only proper) PDO tutorial
     * @link https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting PHP error reporting
     * 
     * @param Book $book A book.
     * @return Book The updated book.
     * @throws \Exception Transaction failed.
     */
    private function updateBook(Book $book): Book {
        $sql = 'UPDATE books SET author_name = :author_name, title = :title WHERE id = :id';

        try {
            $this->connection->beginTransaction();

            $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

            $statement->execute([
                ':author_name' => $book->getAuthorName(),
                ':title' => $book->getTitle(),
                ':id' => $book->getId(),
            ]);

            $this->connection->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->connection->rollBack();

            throw $exception;
        }

        return $book;
    }

    /**
     * Insert a book.
     * 
     * @param Book $book A book.
     * @return Book The newly inserted book.
     */
    private function insertBook(Book $book): Book {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO books (author_name, title) VALUES (:author_name, :title)';

        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute([
            ':author_name' => $book->getAuthorName(),
            ':title' => $book->getTitle(),
        ]);

        $book->setId(
            $this->connection->lastInsertId()
        );

        return $book;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the given record to a Book instance.
     * 
     * @param array $record The record to be converted.
     * @return Book A Book instance.
     */
    private function convertRecordToBook(array $record): Book {
        $id = $record['id'];
        $authorName = $record['author_name'];
        $title = $record['title'];

        $book = new Book($authorName, $title);

        $book->setId($id);

        return $book;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the given recordset to a list of Book instances.
     * 
     * @param array $recordset The recordset to be converted.
     * @return Book[] A list of Book instances.
     */
    private function convertRecordsetToBooksList(array $recordset): array {
        $books = [];

        foreach ($recordset as $record) {
            $books[] = $this->convertRecordToBook($record);
        }

        return $books;
    }

}
```

***SampleMvc/Domain/Model/Book/Book.php:***

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\Domain\Model\Book;

/**
 * Book entity.
 */
class Book {

    /**
     * @param string|null $authorName (optional) The name of an author.
     * @param string|null $title (optional) A title.
     */
    public function __construct(
        private ?string $authorName = null,
        private ?string $title = null
    ) {
        
    }

    /**
     * Get id.
     * 
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId(): ?int {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set id.
     * 
     * @param int|null $id An id.
     * @return static
     */
    public function setId(?int $id): static {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the author name.
     * 
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getAuthorName(): ?string {
        return $this->authorName;
    }

    /**
     * Set the author name.
     * 
     * @param string|null $authorName The name of an author.
     * @return static
     */
    public function setAuthorName(?string $authorName): static {
        $this->authorName = $authorName;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the title.
     * 
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getTitle(): ?string {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set the title.
     * 
     * @param string|null $title A title.
     * @return static
     */
    public function setTitle(?string $title): static {
        $this->title = $title;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

***SampleMvc/Domain/Model/Book/BookMapper.php:***

```
<?php

namespace SampleMvc\Domain\Model\Book;

use SampleMvc\Domain\Model\Book\Book;

/**
 * An interface for various data mappers used to 
 * transfer Book entities to and from a persistence system.
 */
interface BookMapper {

    /**
     * Check if a book exists.
     * 
     * @param Book $book A book.
     * @return bool True if the book exists, false otherwise.
     */
    public function bookExists(Book $book): bool;

    /**
     * Save a book.
     * 
     * @param Book $book A book.
     * @return Book The saved book.
     */
    public function saveBook(Book $book): Book;

    /**
     * Fetch a book by id.
     * 
     * @param int|null $id A book id.
     * @return Book|null The found book, or null if no book was found.
     */
    public function fetchBookById(?int $id): ?Book;

    /**
     * Fetch books by author name.
     * 
     * @param string|null $authorName An author name.
     * @return Book[] The found books list.
     */
    public function fetchBooksByAuthorName(?string $authorName): array;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is a very detailed explanation. I’ll take a look at DI, but I think it is beyond my capabilities as a hobby programmer. Many thanks!

Comment: @ewarning You are welcome. Well, now you have another source of knowledge, if you'll sometimes want to learn a bit more :-) Good luck! _PS:_ Indeed, the DI and DI container deserve your in-depth attention.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. At first glance I don’t understand anything, have to take a closer look at that.

Comment: @dakis Informative answer, just a couple questions as someone new to MVC for the web. To my (very limited) understanding, isn't the stuff in the presentation layer (Controllers, Views) not supposed to directly access domain entities? In the `AddBook` Controller though, it directly receives a `Book` from the `AddBook` Service. Also, if the Controller is just supposed to "alter the state of the model", should it depend on and directly update the View? I know this is an older question/answer, but hopefully someone can explain.

Comment: @dakis Thanks for the replies! To your 1st point - I understand the Controllers/Views not receiving domain entities in the constructor, but from what I've gathered in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709412/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-controller-in-the-mvc-pattern-using-php/25709651#25709651), they shouldn't receive domain entities **at all**; the services should just do something w/o returning anything. Your way is more intuitive to me, but it does seem to blur the lines too much between the different layers, which I think could be bad.

Comment: @dakis I suppose Services could just return DTOs instead, but imo DTOs seem wasteful, at least at a small scale. I guess it really just depends on the app in question whether a design is "right" or "wrong". In my case (super basic CRUD app), I don't imagine it will be a terrible thing to mix the domain and presentation layers a little bit. Thanks again for the clarification, as well as the link to the basic MVC app example.